# How to configure product flavor in new gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors

I am configuring paid and free version of my app and I got below error. I already configure same before android 3 without problem.

How to fixe it please ?
[image]

Gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "capstone.nanodegree.udacity.com.mypodcast"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

    //flavorDimensions "default"
    flavorDimensions "free", "paid"

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "capstone.nanodegree.udacity.com.mypodcast.free"
            dimension "free"
        }

        paid {
            applicationId "capstone.nanodegree.udacity.com.mypodcast.paid"
            dimension "paid"
        }
    }
}
def AAVersion = '4.4.0'
def GLIDEVersion = '4.3.1'
def supportVersion = '26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that there's entries for both packages in your `google-services.json` .....also, and this might be separate issue, I believe you should only have to define one dimension (both your flavors would have same `dimension` value)

Comment: Thanks @john . There is no entries for free and paid packages. Were do I need to add both packages in my `google-services.json` ?

Comment: Typically these would be added as separate apps in firebase console and would then be included in downloaded `google-services.json` (presumably you're using firebase?)

Comment: Yes I am using firebase. Is it automatically added as seperate app in firebase or Do I need to do some changes ? Please How to make it works?

Comment: If each flavor is going to map to seperate app then you'll need to define each app in your firebase project (config for both apps will then be included in single google-services.json file that you can download from firebase console)...there's more info on this at https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Thanks @john I create free and paid app from my firebase project and that fixe the subject issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Flavors same as you, I'll remove 2 of my flavors and rename for simplicity comparisons:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion googleBuildTools

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
   signingConfigs {
        releaseMyApp {
            storeFile file("$projectDir/../myappkeystore.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv('MYAPP_STORE_PASSWORD')
            keyAlias System.getenv('MYAPP_KEY_ALIAS')
            keyPassword System.getenv('MYAPP_KEY_PASSWORD')
        }
    }

productFlavors {
    myapp {
        applicationId "com.myApp.one"
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"https://api.myappone.com"'
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.18"
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    myappStaging {
        applicationId "com.myapp.one.staging"
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"https://stg.api.myappone.com"'
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.18"
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        productFlavors.myapp.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseMyapp
        productFlavors.myappStaging.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseMyapp
    }
}
```

without issues, but i'll post in case there is something different that you notice that I didn't, but your error is probably related to your firebase json. You can use the same json file for all your flavors, you just need a client section for each application identifier. which you can create online through firebase portal.

I made the mistake of making individual firebase json files for each flavor and later figured out I didn't need to do that as they were all identical with all clients in them.

Originally I only used flavors for two different application types, but later had to make flavors for staging as well to support PUSH in multiple environments. Goodluck. Hopefully that helps, but I'm guessing you need to fix your firebase json file.